# Dynamically created ImageButtons not visible

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I'm trying to create an array of ImageButtons that are all displayed within the bounds of the screen with one of 3 images randomly chosen. The issue is most buttons appear off screen/not at all. I've checked the coordinates at run time and they are all within the bounds of the screen, but I cannot see the image. Most of the time I am able to see one, sometimes two. There should be 12 total.

Width and height are metrics of the screen calculated in onCreate(), where createBalloons() is also called. The images[] array contains the id's of drawables.

```
private void createBalloons() {
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

    for (int i = 0; i < GameActivity.MAX_BALLOONS; i++) {
        balloons[i] = new ImageButton(this);
        setupBalloon(balloons[i], i);
        layout.addView(balloons[i]);
    }
}

private void setupBalloon(ImageButton b, int i) {
    int imageId = (int)(Math.random() * images.length);
    b.setImageResource(images[imageId]);
    b.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    b.setScaleX(0.4f);
    b.setScaleY(0.4f);
    b.setX((float) (Math.random() * (width - b.getWidth())));
    b.setY((float) (Math.random() * (height - b.getHeight())));
    b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: well you have to set layout params and add image what you want ??

Comment: you need to set Widht, and height from your button.

Comment: I think you will not be able to do what you want with a `LinearLayout`, try with a `FrameLayout` instead.

Comment: take LinearLayout with vertical orientation in ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

replace setUpballons with this

```
private void setupBalloon(ImageButton b, int i) {
    int imageId = (int)(Math.random() * images.length);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    b.setLayoutParams(params);
    b.setImageResource(images[imageId]);
    b.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    b.setScaleX(0.4f);
    b.setScaleY(0.4f);
    b.setX((float) (Math.random() * (width - b.getWidth())));
    b.setY((float) (Math.random() * (height - b.getHeight())));
    b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Also, as u mentioned 12 buttons there is sheer chance your layout wont be hold all of them, try setting ScrollView as parent for LinearLayout.